# Faster technique for integer equality in C

Tags: c

I am writing a function which checks if two integers are same .I wrote it in two different manners.I want to know if there is any performance difference

**Technique 1**

```
int checkEqual(int a ,int b)
{
    if (a == b)
    return 1;  //it means they were equal
    else 
    return 0;
}
```

**Technique 2**

```
int checkEqual(int a ,int b)
{
    if (!(a - b))  
    return 1;     //it means they are equal
    else 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I want to know if there is any performance difference" - time their execution then

Comment: why dont you just `return (a == b);`? Or better performance `#define checkEqual(a, b) ((a) == (b))`

Comment: Why don't you leave microoptimization to the compiler? You don't know your CPU better that the compiler does.

Comment: Any half-decent optimizer will turn those into *exactly* the same code. Write for readability first. Optimize -- if profiling *proves* you must -- later.

Comment: If you'll check, don't forget about `if(x ^ y) return 0; else return 1;` :)

Comment: @iharob Writing macros to get faster code is a 1980s mindset. Let the compiler worry about inlining functions. Or if you absolutely must worry about it, the inline keyword has been part of the C language for the past 15 years.

Comment: What do you think about `return a^b` ?

Comment: `a - b` may invoke undefined behavior

Comment: if it doesn't slow down, **DON'T** optimize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense whatsoever to discuss manual code optimization without a specific system in mind.

That being said, you should always leave optimizations like these to the compiler and focus on writing as readable code as possible.

Your code can be made more readable by using only one return statement. Also, indent your code.

```
int checkEqual (int a, int b)
{
  return a == b;
}
```

Comment: Most of the time spent here will be function call overhead. You can eliminate that by making the funtion `inline`, or a macro, or just not using functions for silly things.

Answer (score 6):

In short, there is **no** difference of performance.

I compiled each techniques using gcc-4.8.2 with `-O2 -S` option (`-S` generates assembly codes)

**Technique 1**

```
checkEqual1:
.LFB24:
    .cfi_startproc
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpl    %esi, %edi
    sete    %al
    ret
```

**Technique 2**

```
checkEqual2:
.LFB25:
    .cfi_startproc
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpl    %esi, %edi
    sete    %al
    ret
```

These are exactly the same assembly code.
So these two codes will provide the same performance.

**Appendix**

```
bool checkEquals3(int a, int b) { return a == b; }
```

provides

```
checkEqual3:
.LFB26:
    .cfi_startproc
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpl    %esi, %edi
    sete    %al
    ret
```

**exactly the same assembly code too!**